# Designing persistence schema for BigTable on AppEngine

Tags: database-design, relational-database, google-cloud-datastore

I have tried to design the datastore schema for a very small application. That schema would have been very simple, if not trivial, using a relational database with foreign keys, many-to-many relations, joins, etc.

But the problem was that my application was targeted for Google App Engine and I had to design for a database that was not relational. At the end I gave up.

Is there a book or an article that describes design principles for applications that are meant for such databases?

The books that I have found are about programming for App Engine and they don't spend many words about database design principles.

Comment: There are no Design Principals for NoSql! It Name Value Pair Wild West!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, creating a data model for a NoSQL database is no different than for any other database (remember *No* stands for *NotOnly*). You should still look for cohesive objects that you can name and describe as:

- entities (or in some cases: documents)
- attributes
- associations/relationships between entities

The difference to a traditional relational model may come from particularities of the NoSQL DB used, or the scenario you are trying to achieve (i.e. optimize for frequent reads, writes, udpates). For example, in a GAE application you can optimize read access by explicitely modeling parent/child relationships, keep data consistent by entity groups, and multi-valued properties to improve multi-entity join operations.

There is some good documentation on this (related to GAE) by the folks at Google and others:

- [Datastore Overview (Python)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview)
- [Entities, properties and keys (Java)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities)
- [Data Modeling and Scalability in Google App Engine (Python examples)](http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-modeling-scalability-google-app)

BTW, GAE also provides [support for relational DBs based on MySQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)